# How to link an image in markdown and also resize the image?

Tags: css, github, markdown

I've been trying to link an image for my GitHub's project readme, and used this syntax to link the image:

```css
[![alt text](https://link-to-my-pic.png)](https://www.youtube.com/youtube-id)
```

And it works.
But, I want to resize my image.
Somehow, I can't manage to resize it and still make it linkable-
can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Raw HTML needs to be used to change the image size in Markdown.
[How to use an image as a link in HTML](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-use-an-image-as-a-link-in-HTML).
`<a href="link destination"><img src="image address"></a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markdown does not allow for defining the `width` on an image. And Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags.

So, you'll need to use a regular `<a>` tag with `<img>` tag, with a `width` attribute.

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/youtube-id">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x350" width="200" />
</a>
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't change the image size in the GitHub preview... I copy-pasted this code and changed the paths. The image is fine and the link is fine, but if I change the Npx to any number the preview won't change.

Comment: @Yoni It seems that style attribute is removed when showing preview

Comment: @jcubic so do you think it will work when I actually update the file? or is there another way?

Comment: It seems Markdown is not processed within block-level HTML tags. The `<div>` with Markdown experiment worked in an online Markdown editor, but not in Github itself. I've updated the solution.